Get WordPress page with its template
I need to turn an existing WordPress site with multiple pages into a single page.
My hope was to simply get the pages and echo them one after another to create a SPA, like this:
$id = %PAGE_ID% ; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $post->post_content; 

Using the code above to get the needed pages via their IDs does not provide me with the pages how they are currently displayed.
I only receive the actual page content, which could be empty and use a custom template to display and format specific posts, media or other things.
I would like everything in each page-ID.php to be echoed after another, just without the get_header() and get_footer() parts.
Is there any way to do this using WordPress functions or will I have to hack something together?

I don't think there is a default mechanism for something this specific and particular. Maybe you could modify the header and footer template of your theme, so that those somehow recognize the "context" (global variable, if nothing else helps?), and simply output nothing in this situation?

@Cbroe thanks for the ideas. I'll probably just rewrite the page templates to be functions and then include them to echo their contents. Just hoped there would be a more elegant solution :)
